# Why are my injectors different colors when they all have the same flow rate?

Tags: fuel-injectors, mazda-626

As can clearly be seen in the picture, the injectors on my 98 Mazda 626 2L GF are different colors:

[image]

This is even mentioned in the official Workshop Service Manual:

[image]

However, both according to the manual and my tests, all the injectors have the same flow rate; about 56-61ml when held open for 15 seconds.

The issue is that I ***may*** need to replace my injectors, yet [when I look on Rockauto](http://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/mazda,1998,626,2.0l+l4,1316183,fuel/air,fuel+injector,6224), all the injectors seem to be sold individually, and all the ads recommend replacing them as a set, yet with no mention of color.

So what is the significance of the color, and as a bonus, how can I order replacement injectors if no mention of color is made on any of the injectors being sold?

Comment: This is the crazy mixed up world of Ford/Mazda! :o) Really, I have no clue.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Could it be something like the spray angle?  I really don't want to buy a set of four injectors and then have a problem.

Comment: So far I've found someone saying the color isn't significant, and is only for user friendliness when hooking them up: https://www.mazdas247.com/forum/showthread.php?43822-Injector-Color-WTF&s=1aad34b0def717e885db8c8293a28258&p=607666&viewfull=1#post607666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I e-mailed Rockauto about the injector color issue and this is what they said:

> Hello,
>
> All of the information we have on the products we sell is listed on
>   our website. Please see our Help page: Choosing a Part.
>
> If you're not seeing the details you are looking for, we do not have
>   them. That also means they are not important for fitment. The
>   manufacturer always lists the details that will be important to
>   determine if the part will fit your vehicle.
>
> Thank you,
>
> Dave B.   RockAuto Customer Service

I also found [this post](https://www.mazdas247.com/forum/showthread.php?43822-Injector-Color-WTF&p=607126&viewfull=1#post607126) while searching around on the internet:

> The injectors operate in banks driven by the pulses on the same timing
>   as the two coils. They are color coded so that the wires that feed
>   them will never be hooked up incorectly. If they get mismatched the
>   fuel will come out at the wrong time in the firing sequence.
>
> So if you buy new injectors are they going to be different colors too?
>
> if you buy, OEM replacements yes.
>
> if you buy aftermarket injectors from a company like RC, they won't
>   be.
>
> they are only color coded by mazda so that its more user friendly to
>   hookup.

Between the two, I'm going to say that the color must not make any difference and is just some kind of convenience thing.

**EDIT Feb. 5th 2017**

Apparently, the 626 sold in North America, and the one sold in the rest of the world use completely different injectors, and probably a different manifold as well since the US injector is way fatter than the European one:

[image]

So I'm having to RMA the injectors I ordered and look for an exact fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing ALL, the color won't matter.  If you are only replacing one or some, the color must match those already in the vehicle.